# PhpStorm with JSHint linter warns of undeclared classes

Tags: phpstorm, jshint

First time user of PhpStorm. I just opened it (eval) and started looking at an existing, operating project, with PHP & Javascript.

I enabled the built-in JSHint linter, which immediately started warning about undefined classes in a library I use.

These classes **are** of course defined, in a subdirectory of the main project root, which I've also marked as a "Source" directory.

I tried clearing the cache and restarting, no change.

I can find no other way to tell the tool where to look .. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a problem of PHPStorm - it's a JSHint 'feature'. JSHint works on per-file basis and doesn't 'see' variables defined in other files unless they are added to 'global' list. This can be done by either adding the corresponding comments (`/* global MY_LIB*/` - see http://www.jshint.com/docs/) in code, or by adding variables/functions you'd like to use globally to the 'Predefined' list in `Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | JSHint`, `Predefined (,separated)`:

[image]